# File Mode Specification Error: (Invalid-function) Ledger-mode

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I am trying to set my default mode for `.dat` files to be `ledger-mode`. I am using spacemacs. I added `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.dat\\'" . ledger-mode))` to my .spacemacs file. It now correctly loads my `.dat` files in ledger-mode. However, it throws the error: `File Mode Specification Error: (invalid-function \.dat\')`

I have no idea what I did wrong or how to fix it so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your syntax looks correct, maybe grep your config for ".dat" to see if you accidentally added it somewhere else?

Comment: Yup that was it. There was an extra one in a place it shouldn't have been. Thank you!